# Why is not $\infty$ allowed as a values of Lebesgue integral?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

$\infty$ is allowed as a value of Lebesgue measure $m(E)$ and function $f(x)$, but why do not we say $\int_E f= \infty$?

Comment: I think it is because we define $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if $\int_E f <\infty$.

Comment: We do in some cases, e.g., $f$ nonnegative.  However, note that $\int_E f=\infty$ "exists", but $f$ is not integrable.

Comment: Why do we restrict the definition of integrability to the case $\int |f| < \infty$? What if we allow $\infty$?

Comment: We do allow integrals to have the value $\pm\infty$. On the other hand, if certain regularity conditions (such as integrability, $L^p$-condition, uniform integrability, etc) are met, we can say much interesting things, so we often restrict our focus on such functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lebesgue integral of  a nonnegative  function can be $+\infty$. However, we define integrability for nonnegative functions as the condition that $\int_E f < +\infty$.

To extend the integral to general functions we define

$$\int_E f =\int_E f^+ - \int_E f^-$$

This is always possible only for the class of integrable functions where $\int_E f^+ + \int_Ef^-=\int_E |f| < +\infty$ since $\infty - \infty$ is indeterminate.